# Implementing Baritone API into a Minecraft Forge mod

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently making a 1.12.2 Forge mod that involves pathfinding, so I decided to use Baritone. Can anyone help me with actually accessing the API? What I'm currently doing is manually accessing it with `BaritoneAPI.getProvider()`, which crashes it.

According to the author of Baritone, "Baritone's forge jar is notch mapped, and relies on runtime remapping to searge. If you manually load the `BaritoneAPI` class, or otherwise trick forge into thinking that it doesn't need to remap baritone, it will crash like this."

What's the proper way of accessing the Baritone API?

Update: I've resorted to using `EntityPlayerSP#sendChatMessage(String)` and forcing the player to use a Baritone chat command for now.

Comment: Not sure why you posted here *and* on [the Forge forums](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/78182-implementing-baritone-api/). If no one there knows, no one here is either. Have you tried asking the author of Baritone?

Comment: @Draco18s I posted on both because I thought I would get a quicker answer on one of them. I haven't asked the author because I didn't want to bug him and thought someone else would know. I will do that if I can't find another good solution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't try it at the moment, so I don't know if this leads to the problem you mentioned, but it looks like it should be easy enough to use the API.

From [here](https://github.com/cabaletta/baritone#api):

```
BaritoneAPI.getSettings().allowSprint.value = true;
BaritoneAPI.getSettings().primaryTimeoutMS.value = 2000L;

BaritoneAPI.getProvider().getPrimaryBaritone().getCustomGoalProcess().setGoalAndPath(new GoalXZ(10000, 20000));
```

Another thing to note is that when using the API you must use a special release.

From [here](https://github.com/cabaletta/baritone/blob/master/SETUP.md#artifacts):

> Please note that usage of anything located outside of the `baritone.api` package is not supported by the API release jar.

Which refers to the [specially packaged API releases](https://github.com/cabaletta/baritone/blob/master/SETUP.md#artifacts), which can be found [here](https://github.com/cabaletta/baritone/releases).